# In JQuery, how to pass the element that was clicked to the method that is called on onclick event

Tags: jquery

I have several of these lines on a page:

```
<div class="save-button" onclick="Save()">Save</div>
```

In my `Save()` method I want to manipulate the div that was clicked to call the `Save()` method.  How do I pass that in (I think  `$(this)` ), without resorting to ids?

Many thanks!

Comment: More information if you would like a clearer answer but if Save() method is bound to your click event then yes $(this) will work.

Comment: Answererd your own question. This will refer to the element that was clicked initially.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Either remove the `save()` and use [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to catch the event:

```
<div class="save-button">Save</div>
<script>
$('.save-button').click(function () {
    // Now the div itself as an object is $(this)
    $(this).text('Saved').css('background', 'yellow');
});
</script>
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/zRrqh/) ]**</sup>

Or if you insists on using such function as `save()`:

```
<div onClick="save(this)">Save</div>
<script>
$(function () {
    save = function (elm) {
        // Now the object is $(elm)
        $(elm).text('Saved').css('background', 'yellow');
    };
});
</script>
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/zRrqh/1/) ]**</sup>

**EDIT (2015):** *.on('click', function)*

```
<div class="save-button">Save</div>
<script>
$('.save-button').on('click', function () {
    // Now the div itself as an object is $(this)
    $(this).text('Saved').css('background', 'yellow');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I will add: If you are using the second "save() method" on a anchor-link, then you must also cancel the link-action by adding `return;` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 5):

Inside the event handler, `this` refers to the clicked element. However, inside the function you call from the event handler, which is `Save`, `this` will refer to window.

You can explicitly set what `this` should refer to inside `Save` via [`call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) (or `apply`):

```
onclick="Save.call(this, event || window.event);"
```

then you can use it inside the function as `$(this)`:

```
function Save(event) {
    // `this` refers to the clicked element
    // `$(this)` is a jQuery object
    // `event` is the Event object
};
```

**But** as you are using jQuery, you really should do

```
$('.save-button').click(Save);
```

to bind the event handler. Mixing markup with logic is not a good style. You should separate the presentation from the application logic.

**Or** if you want `Save` to accept an element as parameter, then just pass it:

```
onclick="Save(this);"
```

and with jQuery:

```
$('.save-button').click(function() {
    Save(this);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Pretty straight forward...

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(){
   save($(this));
})


function save($obj){
   $obj.css('border', '1px solid red');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply refer to it as: `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Inside the `Save()` function `this` refers to the DOM element that was clicked.</strike>  You can convert this to a jQuery object with `$(this)`.

This refers to `window` by default however, so you'll need to pass `this` as a parameter of the Save function:

```
<div class="save-button" onclick="Save(this)">Save</div>

function Save(div) { }
```

now inside Save, you can use `div` to refer to the div that was clicked.

I was confused about how `this` behaved.  This link helped me:  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: No, it does not. Inside `Save`, `this` refers to `window`.

Comment: You're right.  To get `this` to refer to the div, you'll need to pass it into the save function.  See my edit.

Comment: Also, you cant simply use `div`, it must be as an object `$(div)` in jQuery. Otherwise it wont act just like $(this) would.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pass element as "this" to the function and then wrap it by $(), then you can do anything to it.

```
Html:
<div class="save-button"  onclick="Save(this)" >  Save </div>
JQuery script:
function Save(element){
                // Convert it to jQuery object by wrap in into $()
                $(element).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

<div class="save-button"  onclick="Save(this)" >
 Save
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

});
function Save(element){
                // Convert it to jQuery object by wrap in into $()
                $(element).hide();
}
</script>
```

[1](https://jsfiddle.net/Amir978/7q914z6m/5/)