# Changing image when div is active on SlideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I currently have a setup with three seperate buttons that open three divs. I want one div (namely lockedin) to be open at the start. Furthermore, the divs should close when another is opened by the buttons, which I have accomplished now.

There is one more thing I require and cannot seem to get working properly. Is there a way to show which div is currently active? So when the page is loaded, button2 shows an orange filled button (which I have as an image) and the other two buttons show the white filled button. When another div is selected by means of for example button 1, the button 2 should change to the white filled button, and the button 1 should change to the orange filled button. I have the image SRC's, but just don't know how to select the image based on the active state of its given div.

Thank you in advance.

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    
    //Start of Jquery


 $('.button1').click(function(){
  if ($('.product').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('.product').slideToggle('slow');
        }
        
     $('.developers').slideUp();
     $('.lockedin').slideUp();  
   });

 $('.button2').click(function(){
   if ($('.lockedin').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('.lockedin').slideToggle('slow');
    }
    $('.product').slideUp();
    $('.developers').slideUp();   
});

 $('.button3').click(function(){
  if ($('.developers').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('.developers').slideToggle('slow');
    }
     $('.product').slideUp();
     $('.lockedin').slideUp();
   });
  

    // End of Jquery
});
```

```css
.product {
  display:none;
  color: yellow;
}

.lockedin {
  color:yellow;
}

.product_active{
  display:none;
  }

.developers {
  display:none;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://www.mindaffect.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/product-holder.png" class="button1" alt="Expand"/> 

<img src="http://www.mindaffect.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/product_active.png" class="product_active" alt="product_active" />

<img src="http://www.mindaffect.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/lockedin-holder.png" class="button2" alt="Expand"/> 

<img src="http://www.mindaffect.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/developers-holder.png" class="button3" alt="Expand"/> 

<div class="product">
 Testdiv1
 </div>
 
 <div class= "lockedin">
 Testdiv2
 </div>
 
 <div class = "developers">
 Testdiv3
 </div>
```

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hx9L0h85/

Comment: Hint: Instead of having 2 buttons for each option you can have a single button with 2 states: normal (let's say with class: my_btn) and active (with classes: my_btn and active). In CSS you will have .my_btn { default styles } and .my_btn.active { styles for active state }. In jQuery you can use addClass('active'), removeClass('active') or toggleClass('active').

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In JQuery, how to pass the element that was clicked to the method that is called on onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519815/in-jquery-how-to-pass-the-element-that-was-clicked-to-the-method-that-is-called)