# "this" being rendered as a normal text in Razor view in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, razor, this

I have been trying to pass `this` in my `onclick` to my `InsertNote()` function in my Razor view with some other params.

**Razor:**

```
@{
  foreach (var item in Model.Notes) {
     <a href="#" onclick="InsertNote(@item.NoteNo, @item.NoteCode, this)">Save</a>
  }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function InsertNote(noteNo, noteCode, thisElement) {
  $(thisElement).doSomething();
}
```

As you can see, I have two other params that I have been passing with and `this` is just being rendered as a normal text somehow. I want to be able to do something using in jquery with it.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Are there any solutions beside using jquery's `data-` properties and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520105/8586704)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was working just fine. It was just Razor rendering it as text. But it's still being read as the `this` of the `a` element. Phew!

**Working:**

```
@{
  foreach (var item in Model.Notes) {
    <a href="#" onclick="InsertNote(@item.NoteNo, @item.NoteCode, this)">Save</a>
  }
}
```

**Still working**

```
@{
  foreach (var item in Model.Notes) {
    <a href="#" onclick="InsertNote(this)">Save</a>
  }
}
```